# Capture what a Python function prints out in 3.3?

Tags: python

I'm calling a function and trying to capture the output it prints out, but in 3.3 I don't have access to StringIO.   Is there another method around this?

Comment: [subprocess.check_output](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: This is a little confusing, both because 3.3 does have `io.StringIO` and because it's not clear how `StringIO` would capture the output, unless the function accepts a filelike output target or you rebind `print` or something.

Comment: Thanks...don't know why I couldn't find StringIO before :)

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3, [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) lives in the `io` package. So you can still use it to capture the output:

```
>>> def someMagicFunction ():
        print('foo bar baz')

>>> import io, sys
>>> original = sys.stdout
>>> sys.stdout = new = io.StringIO()
>>> someMagicFunction()
>>> sys.stdout = original
>>> print(new.getvalue())
foo bar baz
```

Comment: Thanks...don't know why I couldn't find StringIO before :)

Answer (score 0):

How about setting up basic logging:

http://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Here is the basic tutorial link:

http://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

`StringIO` has moved in Python 3. Try `from io import StringIO`. You also need to decide whether you want a `StringIO` or a `BytesIO`.

However, it sounds as though you're trying to monkey-patch over `sys.stdout` in (something like) a unit test. I wouldn't recommend doing this in your tests unless you're sure you need to; it'll make for hard-to-maintain tests. I'd suggest that your code needs refactoring - consider changing your function to return a string, which clients can print (or write to a file, or display on a GUI, or...) at their leisure.